# Convert string to date type in visual basic

Tags: vb.net, string, date

I'm trying to convert the retrieved string of date from access database to become date type to do the calculation of months.
The problem i'm having is unable to convert the retrieved string type variable to date type. I tried a few methods such as Convert.ToDateTime, DateTime.ParseExact().. still fails

My code is able to retrieve a column of the permitEndDate as string but unable to convert it to date type cause i need to pass it to my function.

Please help cause i'm new in VB and many thanks to those who read my questions.

My code:

```
    For i As Integer = 0 To ds.Tables("lecturer").Rows.Count - 1

        TextBox1.AppendText(ds.Tables("lecturer").Rows(i).Item(16) & vbCrLf)
        'convert string to date type
        Dim getDate As String = ds.Tables("lecturer").Rows(i).Item(16)
        TextBox1.AppendText("Parse getDate: " & getDate & vbCrLf)

        Dim expDate As DateTime = DateTime.ParseExact(getDate, "dd/MM/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
        TextBox1.AppendText("Parse expDate with date type: " & expDate & vbCrLf)
        ' Dim permitEndDate As String = ds.Tables("lecturer").Rows(i).Item(16)

        'expDate = Convert.ToDateTime(permitEndDate)
        ' TextBox1.AppendText("Difference in month: " & CalculateMonth(expDate) & vbCrLf)
    Next
```

The function :

```
'calculation of months
Function CalculateMonth(ByVal endDate As Date) As Integer
    Dim result As Integer
    '1.get today date
    Dim currentDate As Date = Date.Now.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy")

    'calculation formula
    result = DateDiff(DateInterval.Month, currentDate, endDate)

    Return result
End Function
```

So, my error "String was not recognized as a valid DateTime." the line is :
 Dim expDate As Date = Date.ParseExact(getDate, "dd/MM/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)

Comment: Firstly, why is the data in the database as text if it represents dates? Access has a `Date/Time` data type so why not use that?

Comment: Assuming that you don't have control over the database and must accept the data as text, what format is that text in in the database and can it be null?

Comment: Also, this is crazy: `Dim currentDate As Date = Date.Now.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy")`. Why would you convert a `Date` to a `String` and then expect it to be implicitly converted back to a `Date`? If what you want is today's date with the time zeroed then you should be using `Date.Today`.

Comment: i do not use the date/time in access cause the form i let the user type in the date so i used string. The second of u comment the column cannot be null.Thanks for u guidance on the today date ~ the format of my date is : dd/MM/yyyy...So is there other method to display it for the calculation later on

Comment: The fact that the user enters the date is absolutely not justification for not using the `Date/Time` data type in Access. I would suggest using a `DateTimePicker` or equivalent control but even if you use a `TextBox`, the correct thing to do would be to validate the user's input and convert it to a `Date` first and then save that to the database.  You can use `Date.TryParse` to do both the validation and the conversion.  You should fix your database now and then your current issue simply goes away.

Comment: Can you show me the code sample on how to convert the string form DateTimePicker to Date before insert to database, cause i'm having problem to convert string to date type? Thanks

Comment: If you use a `DateTimePicker` control then there is no conversion required. The control handles all the validation for you and you simply get a `Date` ready to go from its `Value` property.

Comment: If you save the exact information that the user entered, then there's no way to convert that to a date. There are 100s of different way to write a date, that's not counting all the errors the user will write. Your UI need to validate the date is in a proper format and save it to the database as a date. (the user might write /, or -, or space, jus numbers, month name, grammatical error in month name, yyyymmdd, mmddyyyy, ...). What is the value of getDate when you have the error?

Comment: Thanks,  jmcilhinney. It solved the problem for now as i used datetimepicker.                                                                                                        The value of getDate is :10/02/2016

Answer (score 1):

Please check your column value in table

```
(ds.Tables("lecturer").Rows(i).Item(16))
```

I think that you saved a string that is not matching to be converted into a date.